# getline error, reading every line

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  char input;

  while (true) {
    input = _getch();
    cout << "The input is: " << input << "\n";
  }
  ifstream level1;

  level1.open("level1.txt");

  string str[255];
  while (true) {
    getline(level1 , str );
    cout << str;
  }

   system("PAUSE");
}
```

error im getting:

> no no instance of overloaded function "getline" matches the argument list

what im trying to do is real every line inside the text file

Comment: Why do you need 255 strings??

Comment: @Rakete1111I don't but it's just to check

Comment: @Galik doing it right now

Answer (score 3):

getline take a string as second parameter, not an array of string.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting says `no instance of overloaded function "getline" matches the argument list`.

If you look at `getline` prototype you'll see `istream& getline (istream& is, string& str);` that `getline` expects a `string&`, not a `string[255]&` which is what you are sending it.

Either change your call to `getline(level1 , str[0] );` or change the declaration of `string` to `string str;`

Comment: yea the guy above you helped me out on this, thank you too though by the way how can i check for the file's ending